# Crystal Report Error in File

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Currently I am having a problem with crystal report in my C# windows application.

In VS 2010, I developed a report which has sub reports and it was working perfect in development environment...

In VS 2010, CrystalDecisions.Shared and CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine used  Runtime version v2.0.50727 and version is 13.0.2000.0

**But** when I installed this in client machine, some of the users are not able to print the report.

They are getting the error as:

```
“Problem Printing Note. Error in File CheckList {6A5D4384-37DD-451D-90B0-5B6FD2A71AEA}.rpt”
```

But it still works for my credentials perfectly and for some of other credentials also. I am not even able to debug the issue as I am not getting the error, even when I use their credentials.

My Test environment features

- 64 bit
- SAP Crystal Reports run time engine for .net Framework (32bit)
- SAP Crystal Reports run time engine for .net Framework (64bit)*

Could anyone can help me on this please. I am stuck with this for days: Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: In VS2010, I developed a report which has sub reports and it was working perfect in development environment. 
But it failed in test machine for some of our testers who have different credentials.
They are getting the error as “Problem Printing Note. Error in File CheckList {6A5D4384-37DD-451D-90B0-5B6FD2A71AEA}.rpt”
 But it still works for my credentials perfectly and for some of other credentials also.

Comment: I edited your question for improved the explanation. (Improving format)

Comment: Is all the required software to run crystal reports install on the client pc?

Comment: I've had the same problem after migrating from version CRv25 to CRv26, I reinstalled CR for VS, rebooted, reinstalled CR runtime, rebooted and that solved the issue.